# How to make an exception for the last object in an array?

Tags: javascript

I would like to check for each object if the next object has an timeTrigger. If so do something, but when the script is at the second last object, it will give me an error of `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'timeTrigger' of undefined`. How can I make an exception so if there is no next object in the array, it will still do the thing inside the if statement?

```
var index = 0;

        // Loop through array of data (JSON data) and check if timeTrigger exists
        for (var i = 0; i < root.objectArr.length; i++) {

            var timeTrigger = root.objectArr[i].timeTrigger;
            // console.log(timeTrigger);

            index++;

            if (curVideoTime >= root.objectArr[i].timeTrigger && (root.objectArr[i + 1].timeTrigger != undefined && curVideoTime < root.objectArr[i + 1].timeTrigger) ) { 

                if (root.objectArr[i].timeTrigger != root.triggeredId) {

                    root.triggeredId = root.objectArr[i].timeTrigger;
                    dataController.triggeredEvent(index, timeTrigger);

                }

            }

            // If curVideoTime 5sec ==  call function
            if (curVideoTime > root.objectArr[i].timeTrigger && root.objectArr[i + 1].timeTrigger < curVideoTime) dataController.previousEvents(timeTrigger);
            if (curVideoTime < root.objectArr[i].timeTrigger) dataController.nextEvents(timeTrigger);

        }
```

Comment: You want to skip the current iteration when the object is undefined?

Comment: Check and see if the `Object.key(root.objectArr)` exists

Comment: Yes, so there should be some more lines of code inside the if statement, that check if the last object in an array exists and if so, the next object will be ignored. So the last item will display also in my view.

Answer (score 2):

Add an extra check in your first `if`.
Replace:

```
if (curVideoTime >= root.objectArr[i].timeTrigger &&
    (root.objectArr[i + 1].timeTrigger != undefined &&
     curVideoTime < root.objectArr[i + 1].timeTrigger)) {
```

With:

```
if (root.objectArr[i + 1] && // Check if the next object actually exists.
    curVideoTime >= root.objectArr[i].timeTrigger &&
    (root.objectArr[i + 1].timeTrigger != undefined &&
     curVideoTime < root.objectArr[i + 1].timeTrigger)) {
```

Oh, and you don't need the `()` around the last "and" condition, or `root.objectArr[i].`, since you stored `timeTrigger` in a variable:

```
if (root.objectArr[i + 1] &&
    curVideoTime >= timeTrigger &&
    root.objectArr[i + 1].timeTrigger != undefined &&
    curVideoTime < root.objectArr[i + 1].timeTrigger) {
```

It's an insignificant change, but they're not necessary.

---

Also change this `if`:

```
if (curVideoTime > root.objectArr[i].timeTrigger && root.objectArr[i + 1].timeTrigger < curVideoTime) dataController.previousEvents(timeTrigger);
```

To:

```
if (curVideoTime > timeTrigger && root.objectArr[i + 1] && root.objectArr[i + 1].timeTrigger < curVideoTime) dataController.previousEvents(timeTrigger);
```

Comment: The upvote is there because you're checking for the existence of the actual object before trying to read a property from it which is the correct answer, I however disagree with the entire explanation you gave which is none if that makes sense, e.g. *why does this work? what was wrong anyways?* - this usually helps the OP *understand* the issue rather than just *fix it and come back later with more of the same* :)

Comment: _"the entire explanation you gave which is none"_. I already added a small comment in the 2nd code block.

Comment: Still getting the same error of `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'timeTrigger' of undefined`. I already check if the next object exists with: `root.objectArr[i + 1].timeTrigger != undefined `

Comment: @Caspert in that case maybe not every object has the `timeTrigger` property, expand the check even further by editing `root.objectArr[i + 1] &&` to `root.objectArr[i + 1] && root.objectArr[i + 1].timeTrigger &&`

Comment: Like you said @Cerbrus: *small comment* - I don't think that counts as an explanation in my book, that would be "You'll have to check if an object exists before calling properties on it otherwise you can get the undefined error" - notice that some people might still be novice with JS ^.^ good answer nonetheless ofcourse!

Comment: It gives me no errors anymore, but the last object will be not displayed. I think this one is ignored by the code?

Comment: I don't know... All we can see if the code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. It basically checks if the object for that index exists, if not it skips the current iteration.

```
var index = 0;

// Loop through array of data (JSON data) and check if timeTrigger exists
for (var i = 0; i < root.objectArr.length; i++) {

    if (!root.objectArr[i]) {
        continue;
    }

    var timeTrigger = root.objectArr[i].timeTrigger;
    // console.log(timeTrigger);

    index++;

    if (curVideoTime >= root.objectArr[i].timeTrigger && (root.objectArr[i + 1].timeTrigger != undefined && curVideoTime < root.objectArr[i + 1].timeTrigger)) {

        if (root.objectArr[i].timeTrigger != root.triggeredId) {

            root.triggeredId = root.objectArr[i].timeTrigger;
            dataController.triggeredEvent(index, timeTrigger);

        }

    }

    // If curVideoTime 5sec ==  call function
    if (curVideoTime > root.objectArr[i].timeTrigger && root.objectArr[i + 1].timeTrigger < curVideoTime) dataController.previousEvents(timeTrigger);
    if (curVideoTime < root.objectArr[i].timeTrigger) dataController.nextEvents(timeTrigger);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember to put **as few code as possible inside loops**. It's a waste of resources to put an if clause that will run 20 times if the array has 20 elements. Instead:

```
for(var i=0; i < arr.length-1; ++i) {
  // do stuff with arr[i] and arr[i+1];
}

if(arr.length > 0) {
  // do stuff with last cell, arr[arr.length-1]
}
```

I prefer using i-1 and i instead, so that there isn't a useless -1 operation in the loop's condition. But you might find it less intuitive.

```
for(var i=1; i < arr.length; ++i) {
  // do stuff with arr[i-1] and arr[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`root.objectArr[i + 1].timeTrigger == undefined` is exceeding the bounds of the array. `root.objectArr[i + 1]` is undefined and you are attempting to access `timeTrigger` on it. You need to verify `root.objectArr[i + 1]` is not undefined like `root.objectArr[i + 1] && root.objectArr[i + 1].timeTrigger == undefined`.

However, that's getting very verbose. I'd suggest extracting some local variables so that it's clearer.

**Example:**

```
function log(str) {
    var entry = document.createElement('pre');
    entry.innerText = str;
    document.body.appendChild(entry);
}

var withTrigger = {
    timeTrigger: true
};

var root = {
    objectArr: [withTrigger, withTrigger, withTrigger, undefined, withTrigger]
};

function example() {
    var lastIndex = root.objectArr.length - 1;

    for (var i = 0; i < root.objectArr.length; i++) {
        var currentItem = root.objectArr[i];
        var nextItem = root.objectArr[i + 1];
        var entry = "";

        if (currentItem && currentItem.timeTrigger) {
            entry += "Current; i=" + i + " timeTriger=true";
        } else {
            entry += "Current; i=" + i + " timeTriger=false";
        }

        entry += "\n";

        if (nextItem && nextItem.timeTrigger) {
            entry += "Next; i+1=" + (i + 1) + " timeTriger=true";
        } else if (i == lastIndex) {
            entry += "Next; Out of bounds.";
        } else {
            entry += "Next; i+1=" + (i + 1) + " timeTriger=false";
        }

        entry += "\n"

        log(entry);
    }
}

example();
```

**Output:**

```
Current; i=0 timeTriger=true
Next; i+1=1 timeTriger=true

Current; i=1 timeTriger=true
Next; i+1=2 timeTriger=true

Current; i=2 timeTriger=true
Next; i+1=3 timeTriger=false

Current; i=3 timeTriger=false
Next; i+1=4 timeTriger=true

Current; i=4 timeTriger=true
Next; Out of bounds.
```